# Photoshop Batch Action Save for Web and Devices

Tags: action, photoshop

I created an Action in Photoshop CS4. It's something like this:

1. Open Document
2. Change Canvas Size
3. Save for Web & Devices
4. Close Document

Now, the "Save for Web & Devices" does all nice stuff, including saving it with a specific name to a specific folder.
Somehow, when I try to Batch this Action, I'm not able to tell Photoshop NOT to use the name (and probably location) as defined in the "Save for Web & Devices". As a result, Photoshop keeps on overwriting the output previous files in the batch, leaving me with only the transformed rendition of the last file in the batch.

I tried to select the 'override Save As' checkbox in the batch, but that doesn't seem to influence the behavior of the Save for Web & Devices part of the Action.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7):

Using photoshop batch from bridge does maintain the filename providing you have not changed the original filename whilst setting up the "save for web" action in Photoshop.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to use a batch to "Save for web and devices" and have the saved files keep their original name, without the need for a droplet.

To verify if your Action will maintain the original name or override the same file many times you can check the Action in the Actions Panel, Unser the "export" command you will see the "In" property.
If that includes just a path without a file name then it will work as expected, however if it includes a file name at the end of the path then the problem of overriding will occur.

The trick is when recording the Action. After clicking "Save for web and devices" you cannot change the Filename when you save it. (Also I think clicking in the wrong way when saving might also cause the problem)

I think this is what Ben was trying to say in his post above, I just thought I would clarify.

Win7 64bit, CS5

Comment: Correct. The problem might be that when you record the initial save action the file you use has "unwanted characters" like whitespace etc in the filename. Then the Save for web function automatically alters the filename, which ends up as an absolute filename in the action.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is so simple, that I don't now why so many posts. Adobe RULES.

**Simply do this:**

Record NEW Action: Open any image than select form menu SAVE FOR WEB AND DEVICES (select your desired settings and click save).

Then go to Action panes and delete the first part of action *Open File* and run your Batch from menu File>Automate>Batch and that's all.

Comment: If you work on a file that's already open, you don't need to include the extra step of "[deleting] the first part of action *Open File*"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, however found that in my action when I chose to Save for Web by using the shortcut command (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S) that it did not work, but if I used the file menu then it did. If that doesn't work have a play around with your action.

Charlotte

Answer (score 1):

you'd think that by now adobe would have included the ability to easily batch this. the save for web reduces file size by over 50% in most instances, WTF adobe?

Answer (score 1):

The droplet doesn't work to compress the image for the web. If you do a Save for Web manually it will save it at about 30% of the size of using the same batch command in the droplet.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 droplets 1 for changing the name, and the other for saving to the web.
see here http://forums.adobe.com/message/3015524

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this problem by changing my images from `CMYK to RGB`. This reduced image sizes by 50%. I could not set this up as a batch process, I had to do it one at a time but it was quicker than Save For Web, although not as effective.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my "workaround" was to toggle dialog screen ON
on "save for web" part of action, and to manually press "save" and enter the name
of file I wanted.

It's not completely automatic, but action works of 95% of the job.
You just have to be there to click "save" and enter file names.

To toggle dialog screen on, click on the empty box, left to the name of the action.

I hope they will correct that somewhere before CS 11 :)

Cheers!

GM.

Answer (score 0):

The Droplet solution suggested by amber works very well.

You can genericize it a bit by creating a container folder on your desktop or somewhere else convenient and just making sure you clear it out after the action is done.

Definitely worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Sjakelien, I understand your dilemma. Your outputted batch files are all overwriting to the first filename you specified when making the action. So instead of ending up with 35 files you are ending up with 1 file which has been overwritten 35 times. Useless.

I tried this with an image file called 'T.LR5001.DI.3.jpg' and I had this problem.

I then tried it with the next image file called 'T.LR5002.jpg' with a new action and it worked fine. You can see in the path (when you maximise the export process within the main action) that the 'In:' destination does not include the end file name, rather a path to the folder ending with a back slash. This is what you want to achieve and I think it has something to do with the file name structure. Perhaps the full stop (period) is involved.

So try setting up the action with a different initial image file. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar situation. And found the solution myself. Just check your filename. Use valid character and remove numbers which appear at the beginning of filename. Good luck!
Thanks to jtheman for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

With large high-res photos (initially from a 24MP camera say) just using 'save for web' still doesnt get you an image which will load quickly, remotely over the internet, into a browser. The trick is to do three steps after you begin recording an action, giving it an appropriate name.

1. Open an image in the source folder
2. Resize it - if landscape use 1200 x 800 at 72dpi, if portrait use 800 x 1200 at 72 dpi or whatever your final image size needs to be in the browser page. The 72 dpi bit is really important - its pointless using any higher resolution as you can't see the difference on a monitor!! Use Bicubic sharper algorithm. You get a big file size reduction from this step.
3. Sharpen it - the downsizing above will reduce the sharpness and leave it blurry - you can be aggressive with this - at least 100 - 150%, 0.3 radius (try it out)
4. Save for web and devices (taking the sRGB colour profile with it) using high or maximum quality preset. You can check the output image size on this screen and estimate the page load time.
5. Close the image without save if you want to keep the original jpeg.

Now delete the 'file-open' step from the Action in the action palette - simply grab it with the cursor and dump it in the bin at bottom right of the palette. The first step should now be the 'Image Size' step.

With no image open in Photoshop, go to the Automate, Batch command and select the source and destination folders for your images and execute, have a coffee and come back to find them all done.

Answer (score 0):

Bruce, unfortunately your understanding of DPI is incorrect.  For screen use, DPI has *absolutely* no relevance - it only has any impact on an image when it is physically printed.  You're right that you can't see the difference on a monitor, but only because 1200x800 px @ 72dpi and 1200x800 @ 300 dpi display identically on a monitor, but referring to the DPI as the resolution is where you're confusing yourself. The DPI (dots per inch) refers only to how densely the pixels in the image would be physically printed, while the resolution (1200x800 in your example) describes how many pixels there are.
It's a *really* common misunderstanding.  With this in mind, your suggestion above of resizing it and then sharpening it prior to using "Save for Web..." is just doing exactly what 'Save for Web...' is going to (allow you to) do anyway.  Look at the "Save for web..." dialogue and you'll see no reference to dpi, but a very obvious ability to set your resolution as you want it.

Back at the original question, in many instances (including one use or "Save for Web...." I use Autohotkey to get around Adobe's batching issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you dont have any forward/backslash in the file name. I am assuming you have a slash in the file name and thats what is preventing the desired result.

Regards!

Bharat Mudgal